# How to tell a hiring committee that my family lives in the city

Tags: application, job-search, faculty-application, application-cover-letter

**How can a job applicant tactfully tell a hiring committee that they particularly want to live in the location where the school is located?**

I am applying for a faculty job in the city where my wife's family lives. I would love to move there to be close to her family when she and I have kids.

The school might be concerned that I would take another offer over theirs. I want to communicate that I would be particularly likely to accept their offer if they made one.

What is an appropriate way to communicate this? I want to avoid inserting unnecessary personal information, like my marital status or sexual orientation.

I'm thinking of something like this toward the end of the cover letter: 
"I am particularly excited about this position for both personal and professional reasons. Most of my family lives in [city] and I would be thrilled to live there."

Comment: IMHO, you answered your own question. It is important to mention (people usually ask if you know the city/have ties on the interview, but earlier doesn't hurt), and a quick mention on the cover letter is what I usually do as well.

Comment: Yes, the cover letter is the place to put this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "I am particularly excited about this position for both personal and professional reasons. Most of my family lives in [city] and I would be thrilled to live there."

That'll do.

And this may indeed matter - from being on recruitment committees in several places that have trouble getting people to move there, signs of interest in the area are helpful.

Comment: Right on the nail - op has phrased it well , honest and direct.

Comment: "places that have trouble getting people to move there" is a key phrase. Probably won't hurt, but I don't think this will affect your chances if the city you want to move to is Boston or San Francisco.

Comment: @AJK True, but there are only a handful of places that don't at least have to do a little bit of selling on "Why you should move here".